# oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to run the code in [GoogleVisionTutorials](https://github.com/DexterInd/GoogleVisionTutorials). I have run the following terminal command correctly:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=filename.json
```

However I am getting the following credential errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "camera-vision-logo.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "camera-vision-logo.py", line 26, in main
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1271, in get_application_default
    return GoogleCredentials._get_implicit_credentials()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1256, in _get_implicit_credentials
    credentials = checker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1207, in _implicit_credentials_from_files
    credentials_filename = _get_environment_variable_file()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1355, in _get_environment_variable_file
    ' environment variable) does not exist!')
oauth2client.client.ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: File vision2-234508-f73783d1ef52.json (pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are executing the code in a different directory where the credentials file is located.

Use an absolute path to reference it:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/file/filename.json`

Comment: No. I have checked it. That's not the case

Answer (score -1):

run 
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

What is your result?

Is it showing 
vision2-234508-f73783d1ef52.json